# not able to identify difference between same value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data inside a table's column. I SELECT DISTINCT of that column, i also put LTRIM(RTRIM(col_name)) as well while writing SELECT. But still I am getting duplicate column record.

How can we identify why it is happening and how we can avoid it?

I tried RTRIM, LTRIM, UPPER function. Still no help.

Query:

```
select distinct  LTRIM(RTRIM(serverstatus)) 
from SQLInventory
```

Output:

```
Development
Staging
Test
Pre-Production
UNKNOWN
NULL
Need to be decommissioned
Production

Pre-Produc​tion
Decommissioned
Non-Production
Unsupported Edition
```

Comment: Please show the query you are having a problem with, sample data and expected results.

Comment: You could look at the binary values and see where it differs; or split it into individual characters and compare each characters value.

Comment: how can we do that @Larnu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a unicode character in there, somewhere. I copied and pasted the values out initially as a `varchar`, and did the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT serverstatus
FROM (VALUES('Development'),
            ('Staging'),
            ('Test'),
            ('Pre-Production'),
            ('UNKNOWN'),
            ('NULL'),
            ('Need to be decommissioned'),
            ('Production'),
            (''),
            ('Pre-Produc​tion'),
            ('Decommissioned'),
            ('Non-Production'),
            ('Unsupported Edition'))V(serverstatus);
```

This, interestingly, returned the values below:

```
Development
Staging
Test
Pre-Production
UNKNOWN
NULL
Need to be decommissioned
Production

Pre-Produc?tion
Decommissioned
Non-Production
Unsupported Edition
```

Note that one of the values is `Pre-Produc?tion`, meaning that there is a unicode character between the `c` and `t`.

So, let's find out what it is:

```
SELECT 'Pre-Produc​tion', N'Pre-Produc​tion',
       UNICODE(SUBSTRING(N'Pre-Produc​tion',11,1));
```

The `UNICODE` function returns back 8203, which is a zero-width space. I *assume* you want to remove these, so you can update your data by doing:

```
UPDATE SQLInventory
SET serverstatus = REPLACE(serverstatus, NCHAR(8203), N'');
```

Now your first query should work as you expect.

(I also suggest you might therefore want a lookup table for your status' with a foreign key, so that this can't happen again).

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07e856985118eb9e8d324ccc06d585ad)

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this type of thing all the time. For stuff like this [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) and [PatReplace8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/patreplace8k) and [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) are your best friends.

Putting what you posted in a table variable we can analyze the problem:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (txtID INT IDENTITY, txt NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT @table (txt) 
VALUES ('Development'),('Staging'),('Test'),('Pre-Production'),('UNKNOWN'),(NULL),
('Need to be decommissioned'),('Production'),(''),('Pre-Produc​tion'),('Decommissioned'),
('Non-Production'),('Unsupported Edition');
```

This query will identify items with characters other than A-Z, spaces and hyphens:

```
SELECT t.txtID, t.txt
FROM   @table AS t
WHERE  PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z -]%',t.txt) > 0;
```

This returns:

```
txtID       txt
----------- -------------------------------------------
10          Pre-Produc​tion
```

To identify the bad character we can use [NGrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) like this:

```
SELECT      t.txtID, t.txt, ng.position, ng.token -- ,UNICODE(ng.token)
FROM        @table                 AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8K(t.txt,1) AS ng
WHERE       PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z -]%',ng.token)>0;
```

Which returns:

```
txtID  txt               position             token
------ ----------------- -------------------- ---------
10     Pre-Produc​tion    11                   ?
```

PatReplace8K makes cleaning up stuff like this quite easily and quickly. First note this query:

```
SELECT      OldString = t.txt, p.NewString
FROM        @table AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.patReplace8K(t.txt,'%[^a-zA-Z -]%','') AS p
WHERE       PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z -]%',t.txt) > 0;
```

Which returns this on my system:

```
OldString          NewString
------------------ ----------------
Pre-Produc?tion    Pre-Production
```

To fix the problem you can use patreplace8K like this:

```
UPDATE      t
SET         txt = p.newString
FROM        @table                                     AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.patReplace8K(t.txt,'%[^a-zA-Z -]%','') AS p
WHERE       PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z -]%',t.txt) > 0;
```